# SQL/Triggers: output shown after a delay

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

[A similar case](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=322012) shows that sometimes a trigger is fired and the dbms_output.put_line stmts. in it are not printed on console immediately, but follow another such stmt in anonymous block/procedure.

Why does this happen? Is it because of the version of Oracle client?
What if two/three such triggers are fired in a sequence?
serveroutput is on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text written to DBMS_OUTPUT is buffered until something calls DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES to retrieve buffered data.  For whatever reason, the tool you're using isn't calling DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES and displaying the data.  However, if you're seeing output from a later statement *before* the output from your trigger it indicates that the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE statements which created that output are being called in that order.

Regarding the question of trigger firing, you need to read through the Oracle Database Concepts manual's section on Triggers.  For 11.1 the Database Concepts manual can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318.pdf).

Share and enjoy.

Comment: So, 'buffer' is the main reason then, eh?  
Will it always behave like this or can we change the settings?

Comment: I don't there's any way to alter this behavior.

Comment: You can get your scripts to manually read from the buffer by calling `DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES ` yourself.